# SQL: How to convert a string to an INT when the string has decimals

Tags: sql, join, inner-join

I am trying to do an inner join on two tables based on employees age, however one table has age without a decimal and one has it with a decimal.

EX:
Table 1 Age: 26
Table 2 Age: 26.0

I have tried to use CAST, but get the error:

> Conversion failed when converting the varchar value '26.0' to data type int.

Here is my code that cause the error:

```
FROM Table1
INNER JOIN Table2
  ON CAST(Table1.age As INT) = CAST(Table2.age As INT)
```

Comment: Tag only the database that you use.

Comment: Maybe the answer to the academic question is (d) change the schema so that birth date is stored. Age at the time of insertion is no good unless you have insertion date too, which, of course is a perverted birth date.

Comment: Which RDBMS are you using (MySQL, Postgres, Oracle, SQL Server, something else)? Please add the tag of your database to your question. See [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/388759/why-should-i-tag-my-rdbms) to know why tagging is important.

Answer (score 0):

You can first convert to decimal and then convert to int; or (string) replace '.0' with '' before casting to int.